# Is the curve parametrised by $\gamma (t) = t^3 + i(1-\cos(t))$ for $ -1 \leq t \leq 1$ smooth?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I began by differentiating with respect to t and got: $$\gamma '(t) = 3t^2 + i \sin(t)\;.$$ and then said that this function is continuous and exists for all values of t. But this answer seemed to simplistic. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You have thus shown that there are no "kinks" in the curve, because the the derivative is continuous. You might want to show that the curve itself is continuous.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk If the curve is differentiable then it must be continuous a fortiori.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk: though, there *is* a kink.

Answer (score 1):

Your computations are corect, but observe that $\gamma'(0)=0$. The definition of smooth curve usually includes that the derivative does not vanish. If you plot the curve, you will see that it is not smooth at the point $(0,0)$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct,

If $\gamma (t) = t^3 + i(1-\cos(t))$ so

$\gamma '(t) = 3t^2 + i \sin(t)\;$

And the function is continuous and exists for all values of $t$

Comment: The question is about smoothness. You missed the key point.

Answer (score 0):

From the expression of $\gamma'(t)$, the tangent vector is

$$T=\frac{3t^2+i\sin(t)}{\sqrt{9t^4+\sin^2(t)}},$$ which has no limit for $t\to0$. Actually it changes sign and there is a cusp.

---

For small $t$, the imaginary part is close to $\dfrac{t^2}2$, and the curve reminds the "canonical" cusp of the semicubical parabola $y^2=x^3$.